# How to use the value of a number type input in a javascript CRUD?

Tags: javascript, forms, crud

I am trying to make a CRUD for pets in javascript, using a form to submit the values which will be displayed on a table.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If all inputs are text, it works. However, when I put the age input as a number, the age field gets on focus and the data isn't submitted.

Can someone explain why this is happening

Here is the code I used:

```
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); onFormSubmit()">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter your pet</legend>
      <label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
      <label for="race">Race: </label><input type="text" name="race" id="race"/><br>
      <label for="age">Age: </label><input type="number" name="age" id="age" max="0" min="20"/><br>
      <label for="obs">Observations: </label><textarea name="obs" id="obs" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
    </fieldset> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit pet"> 
  </form>
  
  <h3>Results</h3>
  <table id="pets">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Race</th><th>Age</th><th>Observations</th><th>Actions</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

```
var selectedRow = null;

function onFormSubmit() {
  var formData = readFormData();
  if (selectedRow == null) insertNewRecord(formData);
  else updateRecord(formData);
  resetForm();
}

function readFormData() {
  var formData = {};
  formData["name"] = document.getElementById("name").value;
  formData["race"] = document.getElementById("race").value;
  formData["age"] = document.getElementById("age").value;
  formData["observations"] = document.getElementById("obs").value;
  return formData;
}

function insertNewRecord(data) {
  var table = document.getElementById("pets").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
  cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = data.name;
  cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = data.race;
  cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cell3.innerHTML = data.age;
  cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  cell4.innerHTML = data.observations;
  cell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
  cell4.innerHTML = `<a onClick="onEdit(this)">Edit</a> <a onClick="onDelete(this)">Delete</a>`;
}
function updateRecord(petData) {
  selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML = petData.name;
  selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML = petData.race;
  selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML = petData.age;
  selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML = petData.obs;
}

function resetForm() {
  document.getElementById("name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("race").value = "";
  document.getElementById("age").value = 0;
  document.getElementById("obs").value = "";
  selectedRow = null;
}

function onEdit(register) {
  selectedRow = register.parentElement.parentElement;
  document.getElementById("name").value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("race").value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("age").value = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("obs").value = selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML;
}

function onDelete(register) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this record ?")) {
    row = register.parentElement.parentElement;
    document.getElementById("employeeList").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
    resetForm();
  }
}
```

(The code isn't mine. I adapted it from this tutorial: https://www.javaguides.net/2020/11/javascript-crud-example-tutorial.html)

Comment: Your "age" input is `type="text"` not `type="number"`

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong code block.

Comment: Check out attributes in your HTML for the input type="number". You have ```max="0" min="20"```. You have to revert it - ```min="0" max="20"```.